# Proof of $\|P\| \leq \|I-P\|$ for L2 norm in Hilbert space when $P$ is a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, projection

Knowing that $P$ is a projection in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, not necessarily orthogonal and that neither $\mathcal{R(P)}$ nor $\mathcal{N(P)}$ equals $\mathcal{H}$, how can we prove the following inequality:

$$\|P\| \leq \| I - P \| $$

for L2 norm using its supremum definition?

$$ ||A|| = \sup_{||x||=1}{||Ax||}$$

I ended up with:
$$
\begin{align*}\
 \|I-P\| &\geq \|I\| - \|P\|   \\
 \| I - P \| &\geq 1 - \|P\|   \\
 0 \leq \| P \| &\leq 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Am I missing some obvious property?

Comment: I am confused by what you mean by "for second norm using its supremum definition." On what space is $P$ defined? A finite-dimensional space, or an arbitrary Banach space? What norm are you using?

Comment: P is a projection in Hilbert space, here we mean L2 norm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT: This answer was posted (long) before OP changed the conditions to $P\neq I$ and $P\neq 0$.]

The claim is false. $P = I$ is a projection.

Moreover, $0\le\|P\|\le 1$ is only true for orthogonal projections. In fact, from $P^2 = P$ it follows that $\|P\| = \|P^2\|\le\|P\|^2$ and thus $\|P\|\ge 1$.

Comment: I am following this summary https://www.math.temple.edu/~szyld/papers/NumerAlg06.pdf, it is a very first proof

Comment: @muhmad Great! There you have the proof on page 312. So, why did you ask?

Comment: because I don't understand how it was concluded, I get the part that $ ||Pu||  = ||x|| = ||\tilde{y} || = || (I-P)w|| $ but the latter inequality is not clear for me

Comment: Well, $\|(I-P)w\|\le\|I-P\|\|w\| = \|I-P\|$.

Comment: Yes that is clear, sorry my last comment wasn't precise the thing is how do you conclude from $||(I-P)w|| \leq ||I-P||$ that $||P|| \leq ||I-P||$

Comment: It is proved that $\|Pu\|\le\|I-P\|$ for all $u$ with $\|u\|=1$. So, $\|P\| = \sup_{\|u\|=1}\|Pu\|\le\|I-P\|$.

Comment: thank you that is exactly what I meant

Answer (score -1):

$$1=\|I\|=\|I-P+P\| \le \|I-P\|+\|P\|$$

If $P$ is a projection in a Hilbert Space, then using $x=(I-P)x+Px$ one sees that $\|x\|^2=\|(I-P)x\|^2+\|Px\|^2$. Taking supremum over all $x \in H$ with $\|x\|=1$, we see that $1=\|I-P\|+\|P\|$.

Like amsmath mentions, $P=I$ is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: Sorry, but this is false. An orthogonal projection has norm one. So, $\|I-P\| + \|P\|=2$.